# How to save colab tensorflow deep learning model in google drive

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, google-colaboratory

I have just begun working with Tensorflow and Colab.
I followed a tutorial online on how to build a simple image recognition model in Colab.
From the tutorial, I was able to build a simple model, without completely understanding every step at this point. 
But what I would like to know is how I can now save the model I built for use elsewhere.
Here is the final bits of code used to build and test the model.

Placeholder:

```
# Initialize placeholders 
x = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, shape = [None, 28, 28])
y = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.int32, shape = [None])

# Flatten the input data
images_flat = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(x)

# Fully connected layer 
logits = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(images_flat, 62, tf.nn.relu)

# Define a loss function
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = y, 
                                                                    logits = logits))
# Define an optimizer 
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(loss)

# Convert logits to label indexes
correct_pred = tf.argmax(logits, 1)

# Define an accuracy metric
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))


print("images_flat: ", images_flat)
print("logits: ", logits)
print("loss: ", loss)
print("predicted_labels: ", correct_pred)
```

Run in session:

```
tf.set_random_seed(1234)
sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(201):
        print('EPOCH', i)
        _, accuracy_val = sess.run([train_op, accuracy], feed_dict={x: images28, y: labels})
        if i % 10 == 0:
            print("Loss: ", loss)
        print('DONE WITH EPOCH')
```

Test on test data

```
# Import `skimage`
from skimage import transform

# Load the test data
test_images, test_labels = load_data(test_data_directory)

# Transform the images to 28 by 28 pixels
test_images28 = [transform.resize(image, (28, 28)) for image in test_images]

# Convert to grayscale
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
test_images28 = rgb2gray(np.array(test_images28))

# Run predictions against the full test set.
predicted = sess.run([correct_pred], feed_dict={x: test_images28})[0]

# Calculate correct matches 
match_count = sum([int(y == y_) for y, y_ in zip(test_labels, predicted)])

# Calculate the accuracy
accuracy = match_count / len(test_labels)

# Print the accuracy
print("Accuracy: {:.3f}".format(accuracy))
```

From the above can someone suggest a bit of code whereby I can save the model to google drive? To be honest I'm not even sure which variable the model is stored in?

Thank you, and sorry for the beginner question.

Comment: Though not exactly what you asked, [this](https://colab.research.google.com/github/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/notebooks/tensorflow/getting-started-keras.ipynb) colab notebook has good instructions for training a model and saving it in a Google Cloud Storage bucket.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll have a look through that asap